# Volume of a region limited by 3 graph : y = $\frac{x}{x^4+x^2+1}$ ,x=1, x = 0 by disc method with y-axis

Tags: integration, reference-request

I am trying to determine the volume of region bounded by y = $\frac{x}{x^4+x^2+1}$ ,$x=1$, $x = 0$ by disc method with y-axis. However, I have stuck at the beginning since I have found no way to find the inverse function of y = $\frac{x}{x^4+x^2+1}$  nor what to exactly do next given that the function is inversible. Based on what little I understand, I am thinking about subtracting the volume of the big cylinder bounded by Oy and x = 1 with the integral of the inverse function bounded by its intersection with Oy and x =1 (multiply by pi) .

Thanks

Comment: The statement of the problem is very confusing. A "plane" does **NOT** have a volume!  And the "disk method" involves rotation about an axis.  Do you mean "the volume of the region created by rotating the area bounded by $y= \frac{x}{x^4+ x^2+ 1}$, x= 1, and x= 0 around the y-axis"?

Comment: Finding the rotated volume does not seem easy at all. Where is this problem from?

Comment: @user247327 very much yes ! I meant the region

Comment: @TobyMak one of my friend asked me to help with his homework, but I struggled too since I take different programs from his. I want to know how to solve this first to explain to him later...